# perl exponentiation results in "nan"

Tags: perl, number-formatting

i have the following problem:
I have a number of values x and I need to compute x^e (e being euler's number).
I do this:

```
$x = $x ** exp(1);
```

This results in "nan" for all of my test cases.

However if I print the values of $x before I do this and then take one and change above line to this:

```
$x = -12.4061063212051 ** exp(1);
```

it results in perfectly fine numbers.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

PS: Maybe the error hides somewhere else, so here is how i compute $x:

```
$y = #some float value taken from the output string of another program
$x = ($y/(303 * 0.0019872041));
print $x; #prints number
$x = $x ** exp(1);
print $x; #prints "nan"
```

Comment: please me that's `x$` is not a typo in your code :D

Comment: are you sure `$x` isn't NaN before that?

Comment: yes, I print it before and after this line

Comment: do you use `use strict; use warnings;` ?

Comment: yes... I get no messages though

Comment: Post the exact value you are using for `$y`

Comment: Well, there's your problem:  you're trying to take a negative number to a positive, non-integer exponent.

Comment: Dump($x) results in 
`SV = NV(0xa9f638) at 0x1451f68
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,NOK,pNOK)
  NV = -12.3894984144833`
before the exponentiation and
`SV = NV(0xa9f638) at 0x1451f68
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,NOK,pNOK)
  NV = nan` after

Comment: @Jack: why is this a problem and why does it work with the hard coded version then?

Comment: @Nick:  See my answer below.  What you're trying to compute is a (non-real) complex number.

Comment: @Nick: The hard-coded version works because it parses differently. Exponentiation has a higher precedence than unary negation. The hard-coded version parses as `-(x ** e)` (that is, the exponentiation happens before the negation). The variable version "hides" the negation inside the value of `x`, so it effectively parses as `(-x) ** e`.

Comment: Ok it turned out that i actually wanted to compute e^x and not x^e ._. Silly me! But I guess I still learned something ;)

Comment: -number** should raise a precedence warning :(

Comment: negative numbers taken to a rational, non-integral exponent should result in a superposition :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's make things a bit easier for the moment, and suppose that we were taking `$x**2.5`.  Well, since `2.5==5.0/2.0`, we have `$x**2.5==$x**(5.0/2.0)==($x**0.5)**5.0`.  Or, in other words, `$x**2.5` is the same thing as the fifth power of `sqrt($x)`.

Since computers tend to only deal with real numbers by default, what do you think would happen if, say `$x==-1`?

Yeah....now, what if `$x<0$` and we wanted to take `$x**exp(1)` (the decimal approximation that Perl uses for `exp(1)` is `2.71828182845905`)?

Answer (score 12):

It's all about operator precedence:

```
$x = -12.4061063212051 ** exp(1);
```

is really

```
$x = - (12.4061063212051 ** exp(1));
```

as seen using

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e'$x = -12.4061063212051 ** $e'
($x = (-(12.4061063212051 ** $e)));
-e syntax OK
```

Which is fine.

If you try the following it will also fail just as your program:

```
$x = (- 12.4061063212051) ** exp(1);
```

And it should, there is no real number that meets this criteria.

Comment: The precedence was surprising, so I added code to demonstrate. Hope you don't mind.